# Distinction with non-finite clause/subordinate clause

Tags: grammar, usage

He left the party and went home, **not having anyone to talk to.**

**A clause is a collection of words that has a subject that is actively doing a verb.*

Non-finite **clauses** contain a verb which does not show tense but have no subject doing a verb so why are they classed as clauses and not phrases.

Comment: Where do you get that definition of a "clause" from?

Comment: https://web.cn.edu/kwheeler/gram_clauses_n_phrases.html

Answer (score 1):

From ["Oxford dictionaries"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/grammar/clauses)

> A clause is a group of words that contains a verb (and usually other components too).

The clause may be active or passive. It may have a finite verb or a non-finite verb.

Some finite verbs do have an explicit subject. At other times the subject is implied by the rest of the sentence.

> He cut the lawn to make the garden tidy.  (infinitive clause giving purpose. Implied subject. *He* made the garden tidy.)
>
> John falling off the table was funny  (gerund clause with explicit subject "John")

Answer (score 0):

A clause with a finite verb is called a finite clause.
A finite clause can be : a matrix (main) clause or a subordinate clause.

A clause with a non-finite verb is called a non-finite clause.
A non-finite clause can be a subordinate clause only.

Finite clauses have an overt or explicit subject whereas non-finite clauses have an implied subject. The subject of the matrix clause is usually the subject of the non-finite subordinate clause.

But a phrase doesn't have a subject, and herein lies the difference.